# How do I check which versions of packages I'm using in GoogleColab?

Tags: version, google-colaboratory

Some are preinstalled in Colab and some installed with `!pip install module_name` in Colab cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to import the module, then run this command:

```
name_of_module.__version__
```

For example:

```
import nltk
import tensorflow as tf
nltk.__version__
# '3.2.5'
tf.__version__
# '2.6.0'
```